# How to change a material offset in HDRP material shader type?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was using Unity in 3D mode than I had to change to HDRP:

```
rend.material.mainTextureOffset
```

and

```
rend.material.SetTextureOffset
```

were working normally but when upgraded to HDRP, they were not affecting the variables and not changing the scene so I thought they could have another parameter name or function.

To change the color of the material I had to change from: `rend.material.SetColor("_Color", colors[0]);`
to `rend.material.SetColor("_BaseColor", colors[0]);`

Comment: It depends on what shaders you're using. Some shaders don't use texture offsets. You can see the supported properties if you look at the material in debug mode. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked by using the same function but changing the attribute name to
**_BaseColorMap**

```
rend.material.SetTextureOffset(
  "_BaseColorMap",
  new Vector2(offset_x,offset_y));
```

and worked perfectly!